# Modifying Window Button Colors in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, user-interface, colors, customization, titlebar

How can I modify the red/yellow/green window buttons for close/minimize/zoom in Mac OS X? There must be an editable resource or plist somewhere.

Here are the buttons I'm talking about:

[image: Mac stoplight buttons.]

For red/green colorblind individuals, those colors can be maddening.  I wish they chose the actual bluish shade of green used in a traffic light instead of the puke grass green.  That grassy green is indeterminable from the red.

Changing the theme to graphite is a poor alternative, so any other method is much preferred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, after a long and seemingly endless research cycle, I've located where the window buttons are stored.  They're in a file called `ArtFile.bin` in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`.

Also, a guy named [Alex Zielenski](http://blog.alexzielenski.com/post/6386231534/lion-and-theming) with the help of [Indragie Karunaratne](http://indragie.com/) created a utility named [artFileTool](https://github.com/alexzielenski/artFileTool) to get to its contents. The second link is the code repository for the utility.

- http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16810624
- https://github.com/alexzielenski/artFileTool

Here's the [process](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=827344#p827344) to extract and then rebuild the resource as described on the MacThemes forum by a user named *toutheme*:

> **For ArtFile.bin - Lion**
>
> ***Preparation***
>
> - Create new folder: TheFolder
> - Copy the Lion ArtFile.bin (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources) and artFileTool on TheFolder.
>
> ***Terminal***
>
> - Launch Terminal, type "cd" + "space" + (drag TheFolder on Terminal window). Type enter.
>
> ***Decoding***
>
> To decode ArtFile.bin and compile a folder Resources Disconnected Classified:
>
> - ./artFileTool -d ArtFile.bin ResourcesDisconnectedClassified
>
>   -- or --
>
> To decode ArtFile.bin and compile a folder Named Connected Images:
>
> - ./artFileTool -d -c ArtFile.bin NamedConnectedImages
>
> ***Edition***
>
> Edit your files with PhotoShop, for example…
>
> **Encoding**
>
> To re-encode the Resources Disconnected Classified:
>
> - ./artFileTool -e ResourcesDisconnectedClassified ArtFile.bin ArtFile.new.bin
>
>   -- or --
>
> To re-encode the Named Connected Images:
>
> - ./artFileTool -e -c NamedConnectedImages ArtFile.bin ArtFile.new.bin
>
> ---
>
> **For ArtFile.bin - Snow Leopard:**
>
> - ./artFileTool -d -l ArtFile.bin ResourcesDisconnectedClassified
> - ./artFileTool -d -l -c ArtFile.bin NamedConnectedImages
> - ./artFileTool -e -l ResourcesDisconnectedClassified ArtFile.bin ArtFile.new.bin
> - ./artFileTool -e -l -c NamedConnectedImages ArtFile.bin ArtFile.new.bin
>
> ---
>
> **For ArtFile200.bin (Lion only):**
>
> - Create new folder: TheFolder
> - Copy the Lion ArtFile200.bin (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources) and artFileTool on TheFolder.
> - Launch Terminal, type "cd" + "space" + (drag TheFolder on Terminal window). Type enter.
>
> ***Decoding***
>
> - ./artFileTool -d ArtFile200.bin ResourcesDisconnectedClassified
> - ./artFileTool -d -c ArtFile200.bin NamedConnectedImages
>
> ***Encoding***
>
> - ./artFileTool -e ResourcesDisconnectedClassified ArtFile200.bin ArtFile200.new.bin
> - ./artFileTool -e -c NamedConnectedImages ArtFile200.bin ArtFile200.new.bin
> - Make sure to check the size of the newly created file. (4.0-5.2 mb)
> - Rename ArtFile.new.bin to ArtFile.bin and replace the one location in the CoreUI.framework directory
> - Logout

I hope this helps anyone who got as frustrated as I did at how difficult it is discovering basic information about the inner workings of OS X.

Comment: Yes and starting with Lion, retina resources are kept in the ArtFile200.bin. Also, there is an entire file-format specification on the ArtFile.bin and SArtFile.bin on the GitHub page for anyone interested. And for your consideration, the code in the repository is reusable in a Cocoa application so you are completely able to create a program to change the titlebarcontrols.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying buttons in MacOSX 10.11 El Capitan can also be done by an Alex Zielenski's tool called "ThemeEngine", found [HERE](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine/releases/tag/1.0.0b1) at github.com.
 You have to edit copies of the

“.car” files   in:   /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources

Each of these .car files contains "WindowFrame_WindowControlButtons" which itself consists of 240 items (!).
I "grouped" those (= button in app window) with first "Size" then "Scale".
Higher resolved "...@x2.psd" items are used for Retina Displays, "small" ones for in-app windows, like the colors palette in TextEdit.

In ThemeEngine graphic items (*.psd!) are selected and sent/received to/from a compatible Editor (eg: Photoshop), but can also be individually dragged to any folder, changed or replaced by other apps (even "Preview") and be re-dragged to any .car-file window in ThemeEngine.

Normally you'd first have to deactivate SIP in El Capitan, but I found it easier to select my "old" Maverick USB drive as startup disk and drag the SystemAppearance.car back into SystemAppearance.bundle manually, then to re-restart (see also "AccessibilityDarkAppearance.car").

I find the new disgustingly-2D icons really amateurish, kind of "deflated" -- so I exchanged them with a set of Maverick-like ones, copied from an older MacOSX. As a compromise I applied the "negative" white plus/minus signs used in El-Capitan.

(Btw: I didn't use the above mentioned artFileTool by Alex to get at the Aqua buttons, but simply made a series of screenshots and cut out the various states of round Aqua buttons.)

If anybody is interested I can post my "SystemAppearance.car" file here ...

Comment: I'm interested in getting Windows XP / 7's window control buttons in my mac.  Is that possible using the tool mentioned above?  I could try it locally if someone shows how to run Themes app locally.

Comment: I think it's actually quite simple – in theory ...    
Problem is, the author of ThemeEngine is about to develop a version 2 that will work with MacOS 10.11+ – meaning if you are on El-Capitan or below: download the old version ("HERE"). If you use (High) Sierra or even Mojave you either have to wait for v.2  – or start your Mac with an older system.
Next, make screenshots of your buttons, load SystemAppearance.car with ThemeEngine, in Preferences choose editor, select menu "Renditions > Send to editor", paste relevant parts of your screenshot into the *.psd file and return to ThemeEngine.

Comment: Me AGAIN: I just re-read my posting above that you, Red Hunt, were referring to and ascertained, that the "primitive" way of dragging buttons' graphics to a finder's folder and editing via an external app STILL works! So, download the app from "HERE", open the *.car file and drag the needed files "outside". Open and replace contents, drag back to their former (exact!) place, save and quit. As said before, you may be prevented from editing the original car-file: Do your changes in a copy and replace this into your system, like described above.

Comment: What is "HERE" here?  Are you referring to the ThemeEngine?

Comment: Please take the time to re-read my article directly above "our" comments. You'll find your answer in line 2 of it: >>"ThemeEngine", found HERE at github.com … << (I simply don't know how to place urls in comments.)

Answer (score -1):

Just as a reminder, the Graphite appearance in Snow Leopard and earlier changed the window buttons to gray. I was quite surprised and unhappy that in Mountain Lion these remain colored even in the Graphite theme. (I forget what Lion did, because I only used it briefly.) It's my machine. I want to change it. Color stands out more than I want and is distracting. It also looks unprofessional. In fact, I used to use Unsanity's Mighty Mouse to turn the stupid colored beachball into something gray.

Comment: How is this an answer to easily modify the button colors?

Comment: *"I was quite surprised and unhappy that in Mountain Lion these remain colored even in the Graphite theme."* While I agree with the rest of your sentiment, this statement is absolutely false. The Graphite theme is fully supported on all versions of OS X, at least up through Yosemite, and it does indeed turn the "traffic light" buttons to gray. I use and have used it.