# kill Mac OSX app if close button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, pyobjc

I want to kill the process window (any process) if the red close button is pressed. Not looking for third party solutions (like RedQuits).

One solution is to do via applescript, but that involves polling, which I am trying to avoid.

I read about **NSDistributedNotificationCenter**, but cant figure out if the browser sends a system notification about close process. For example, itunes sends a notification **com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo** whenever a song is playing/paused. How can I find what notifications other apps are sending? Any help?

Any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to quit your application when the last window is closed, use:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication
```

or are you looking for a way to be notified when a window is going to be closed, use:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillClose:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Comment: I read about this. The problem is, Its not my app I want to close, but I want a solution that works for all existing apps on my system. I thought if we could swizzle applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed at runtime, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

- To find all distributed notifications use the [Notification Watcher by Kevin Ballard](https://github.com/kballard/NotificationWatcher)
- by my first brief look window closed is not sent as notification
- try using the [CGWindow-API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008073-CH2-SW1), that's a much more sensible way than AppleScript to work with windows

Comment: Thanks for the notification watcher. I'll check it out.

Answer (score -1):

[Modifying Window Button Colors in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170717/modifying-window-button-colors-in-mac-os-x)

This is not the answer.. But it may be a kick in the right direction. I will keep my eyes peeled!

Comment: Im not sure how this will help. I am basically looking for some event which gets triggered when I press the red button, so I can catch it.

Comment: ...This article shows locations of the buttons you are trying to configure... Sorry it was not a direct answer.